# Scan bar code and display in textbox and fire click event automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a problem .I have an  form with many text input and buttons .Among all these I have a text box where i add a serial number then click a specific button to add all data in a table below manually button click event is working fine .

But when i use bar code scanner to give input in that serial number text box then the add button click event is not working automatically. For this i added so that the button click events work automatically

```
$("#btnAdd").focus();
```

but it is not working. What I want when the bar code scanner scan a code after inserting it in that textbox only that  `btnAdd` click will be fired automatically.
Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried `$("#btnAdd").click();`?

Comment: for which event i will write this ?? on textbox key up event ??@Philip

Comment: If you need to fire a click event after textbox update/insert you may need to call the .click() method.

Answer (score 0):

Barcode scanners are entering the barcode number and then does an enter. If you have each input ina form it will automaticly submit the form. You dont need to automatize anything by using code.

Answer (score 0):

Barcode scanners have a suffix, usually a `return` key  or 2 `tab` presses, you need to catch those on your input and deal with them as you wish.

For example, if the suffix of your barcode scanner is `return`:

```
$("#myInput").keyup(function(e){
  if (e.which==13) { // 13 is the code for return
     $("#myOtherInput").focus();
  }
  else {
    // Do whatever you like
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```